# getting started with custom templates RMarkdown vitae

Tags: r, package, latex, r-markdown, xelatex

In order to start working with customizing templates for use with the R package "vitae" I did what I thought was the simplest first step: I knit a document with the "awesomecv" template, and then copied that .tex template to my working directory. This had the advantage of generating the supplementary files to ideally be used by the new template in the local directory. I made a small modification to the template, just changing the color to "awesome-emerald" as shown by [my copy here](https://github.com/dendroica/cv)

I changed the output section of the YAML in the .Rmd file in the repository to...

```
output:
  vitae::cv_document:
    template: awesome-cv_mod.tex
```

The rest of the file is otherwise the same as what is in the repository. However, I now get the following error:

```
! Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or
(fontspec)                      LuaTeX.
(fontspec)                      
(fontspec)                      You must change your typesetting engine to,
(fontspec)                      e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex" instead of
(fontspec)                      "latex" or "pdflatex".
```

I changed my engine in the .Rproj file and it shows up correctly as XeLaTeX in the Sweave tab of Project options... but this doesn't get rid of the error. It doesn't make sense to me why that would be required anyway, since it works fine out of the box for this template otherwise. Does anyone have insight into what's going on here? Is this error message true, or indicative that I am missing something in the process? I am running Ubuntu 22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm afraid that the Awesome CV template may only work on lua/xelatex because of it's reliance on the fontspec package. I'll explain how I came to that determination:

1. [The Documentation for the `awesomecv()` function](https://pkg.mitchelloharawild.com/vitae/reference/awesomecv.html) implies that pdflatex is a valid option for the `latex_engine =` argument. However, it errors (as you point out) when it is set to to "pdflatex".
2. Investigating the [readme for the awesomeCV](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV), the usage section only shows the option to run with xelatex.
3. [An issue](https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/vitae/issues/6) open in the `vitae` repo points out the inability to use the "default engine" (pdflatex) for awesomeCV, and the maintainer directs them to set the `latex_engine = xelatex`.

Based on that evidence, I'm inclined to say that this isn't an error in the coding that you've done or the coding of the `vitae` package, but rather, the documentation for the `awesomecv()` function is incorrect in saying that "pdflatex" can be used as the latex_engine.

All that considered, I know you said that you are adverse to changing your LaTeX engine, but that may be the only way to proceed with this template.

**If you wish to continue with xelatex, try the following:**

Change your YAML header to the following for you CV .Rmd:

```
---
name: Jessica
surname: Gorzo
position: "Data Scientist"
pronouns: she/her
address: "Cellular Tracking Technologies"
www: avianecologist.com
twitter: setophaga
github: dendroica
linkedin: gorzo
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %Y')`"
output:
  vitae::cv_document:
    latex_engine: "xelatex" # It is important to specify this
    template: awesome-cv_mod.tex
csl: apa-single-spaced_mod.csl
---
```

That should get you your modified coloring:

[image]

**EDIT for More Clarity on Process**

1. Download the bib, CV rmd, template tex, and csl files from GH and put all into the same folder
2. Open CV rmd, Render once with options as is to make sure I get correct PDF with default options
3. Change YAML options to those show above, selecting the tex template and xelatex engine
4. Render once more - get the correct colored output and all options

Comment: @setophaga, I've edited my answer to include instructions on how to proceed with xelatex if you are interested

Comment: thank you! this indeed gets me to a rendering doc, so this might be a separate question, but interestingly when I knit now with all the component files from the repository with your modification to the output section of the YAML the first sections that are piped into detailed_entries() no longer render correctly for me. I see in your image snippet they're working for you; for me it is just printing the tibble in the doc and not the formatted entries as above

Comment: @setophaga I've added anther section at the end of my answer for my exact process

Comment: Thank you again; I followed your edited steps at the bottom verbatim. I am wondering if maybe the updates I made to tinytex this morning might have caused the change. Will keep working with it to see why detailed_entries() is no longer outputting properly for me

Comment: FYI I added my new file based on your modifications to the repository named mycv_public_mod.Rmd

If you are able, let me know if you spot anything there and/or if pulling that file for you works as expected. This is the one that is still not correctly rendering detailed_entries()

Comment: FYI I opened as a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77318982/detailed-entries-not-rendering-correctly-in-r-vitae-package-with-custom-templa

Comment: @setophaga thank you - I'll re-examine the issues you are having and If I come up with a solution, I will provide more information in your new question

Comment: @setophaga I believe I have created a reproducible workflow for you to folllow on your new question, please review and comment there