# detailed_entries() not rendering correctly in R vitae package with custom template

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, tex, xetex

I have created a very basic modification for a custom template as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77311453/getting-started-with-custom-templates-rmarkdown-vitae). However, when I knit the file [mycv_public_mod.Rmd](https://github.com/dendroica/cv) it does not render detailed_entries() correctly; rather it only prints the tibble() as shown in the output file in the linked repository: mycv_public_mod.pdf

This problem does not appear to be occurring for the user who answered the original question (first link above). I am on Ubuntu 22 and running XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)

I updated all of my R packages last night, and am wondering if there is an update that may have broken the functionality. I also ran the following...

```
sudo R
tinytex::tlmgr_update()
```

It installed updates in /var/lib/texmf/web2c

Let me know if there are any other versions I should check, or if anyone can replicate this problem/provide a solution.

**UPDATE:** I have updated to...

- XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023)
- RStudio 2023.09.1+494 "Desert Sunflower" Release (cd7011dce393115d3a7c3db799dda4b1c7e88711, 2023-10-16) for Ubuntu Jammy
  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) rstudio/2023.09.1+494 Chrome/116.0.5845.190 Electron/26.2.4 Safari/537.36
- R 4.3.1

...and the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

When I attempt to use `rmarkdown::render()` on your "mycv_public_mod.Rmd" file without making any changes - I am greeted with the following error:

```
LaTex Error: File 'awesome-cv.cls' not found
```

Upon looking into the documentation and vignettes for `vitae`, I found this [article](https://pkg.mitchelloharawild.com/vitae/articles/extending.html) on using templates with vitae. In that article, a line under the heading "Using the Template with Rmarkdown" says the following.

> You will also need to copy all of the LaTeX class (.cls) and style (.sty) files provided with the template into the same folder as your rmarkdown document. Once that is done, your new template should be ready to use with the vitae package.

Clearly, I am missing the .cls file that the template must have in order to be used in Rmarkdown. The documentation states that the .cls (and .sty) file(s) would be with the template, so I will start there.

**Step 2**

I start with a folder with the following files provided via your github - only what is necessary to render the Rmd:

- apa-single-spaced_mod.csl
- mycv_public_mod.Rmd
- mypubs.bib

I use `rmarkdown::render()` on "mycv_public_mod.Rmd" with the slightly modified following YAML:

```
---
name: Jessica
surname: Gorzo
position: "Data Scientist"
pronouns: she/her
address: "Cellular Tracking Technologies"
www: avianecologist.com
twitter: setophaga
github: dendroica
linkedin: gorzo
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %Y')`"
output:
  vitae::awesomecv:
    page_total: TRUE
    keep_tex: TRUE
csl: apa-single-spaced_mod.csl
---
```

These YAML options will produce a CV using the `vitae::awesomecv()`. The render succeeds and produces a correctly formatted file:

[image]

My folder now contains the following files after rendering:

- apa-single-spaced_mod.csl (present in og folder)
- mycv_public_mod.pdf (rendered document)
- mycv_public_mod.Rmd (present in og folder)
- **mycv_public_mod.tex (new!)**
- mypubs.bib (present in og folder)
- **awesome-cv.cls (new!)**
- **fonts/ (new!)**

I now have a new .tex file (resulting from the rendering), a .cls file, and a folder of "fonts". I appear to now have what I needed, based on my original error.

**Step 3**

I return to "mycv_public_mod.Rmd" and set the following YAML:

```
---
name: Jessica
surname: Gorzo
position: "Data Scientist"
pronouns: she/her
address: "Cellular Tracking Technologies"
www: avianecologist.com
twitter: setophaga
github: dendroica
linkedin: gorzo
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %Y')`"
output:
  vitae::cv_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex # Specify so it uses this instead of pdflatex
    keep_tex: TRUE # Keep tex file in-between runs
    template: mycv_public_mod.tex # Template that we just made
csl: apa-single-spaced_mod.csl
---
```

When I run `rmarkdown::render()` it once again produces a correctly formatted document using the "template" (which is technically just default awesomeCV) I just made. Adding the .cls file from the template creation appears to have worked and I am able to use the `vitae::cv_document()` function to use a template and create the CV.

[image]

**Step 4**

OP requested the use of a special template to be used that was provided in the github. This time, I will have these files in the folder:

- awesome-cv.cls (created via the `awesomecv()` function and rendering)
- mycv_public_mod.Rmd (from GH)
- mypubs.bib (from GH)
- awesome-cv_mod.tex (from GH; modified and desired CV template from OP)
- apa-single-spaced_mod.csl (from GH)
- fonts/ (folder created via the `awesomecv()` function and rendering)

The most important parts here are that I have the "/fonts" folder and the "awesome-cv.cls" that were both generated with the template.

I prepare "mycv_public_mod.Rmd" with the following YAML:

```
---
name: Jessica
surname: Gorzo
position: "Data Scientist"
pronouns: she/her
address: "Cellular Tracking Technologies"
www: avianecologist.com
twitter: setophaga
github: dendroica
linkedin: gorzo
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %Y')`"
output:
  vitae::cv_document:
    latex_engine: "xelatex" # Need to specify as dependency of awesomeCV
    template: "awesome-cv_mod.tex" # Modified template provided by OP
csl: apa-single-spaced_mod.csl
---
```

I use `rmarkdown::render()` once more, and get the desired result with the
template recoloring.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this walk through! Oddly, the .tex file I have in the GitHub repository still didn't work for me, but, I was able to get the desired results by instead modifying the file generated by "keep_tex" in this answer

Comment: Hi there- I unaccepted the answer because I realized that in modifying the generated tex file from "keep_tex" all the variables were replaced with values. I am hoping to get the template to work that still has the variables, and it is still giving me the same issue described. It sounds like it is not for you but my uploaded tex file in the repository still gives me the printed tibble and not the formatted output

Comment: @setophaga Sorry to hear that it's still not quite working for you. This is definitely a bit odd, because I'm not quite able to reproduce the same problem. I guess you may find some luck in tweaking the steps that I did - good luck!

Comment: indeed it is so weird. i am wondering if anyone can reproduce this issue, and/or if there is versioning etc that might be contributing. thank you so much for taking the time to look at this and getting me further in troubleshooting!

Comment: @setophaga One difference that may be affecting this is that I am using TeXLive on a Linux system. If you have a different distribution of TeX / different OS that may be contributing, but I am not certain.

Comment: ah OK- in the post i put my version of XeTeX and TeX Live on Ubuntu 22; does this match yours out of curiosity?

Comment: @setophaga I am on a rolling release distribution so I am guessing my TeXLive may be more advanced than yours. My version number is 2023.66594-19